# Type error comparing two datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

My problem will look common to you, but I didn't find the answer on the website.
I want to combine two dates in python, I use this :

```
delta = 2012-04-07 18:54:40  - 2012-04-07 18:54:39
```

But I get an error : 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

I understand it, but I don't know how to turn it the right way.

Do you have an idea?

Thks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are subtracting `strings`, not `datetime.datetime` objects. Try the `strptime` method in order to convert from strings to `datetime.datetime`.

```
>>> delta = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-04-07 18:54:40', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') \
            - datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-04-07 18:54:39', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make them datetimes!

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 25, 6, 20914)
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 25, 6, 20914)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 25, 6, 20914)
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 25, 6, 20914) - datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 14, 6, 20914)
datetime.timedelta(0, 660)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate with datetimes, you first have to parse the date strings you've got.

One possibility is strptime, as mentioned. You can also use `python-dateutil`:

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse("2012-04-07 18:54:40") - dateutil.parser.parse("2012-04-07 18:54:39")

# datetime.timedelta(0, 1)
```

which is easier to use. Also, there are a lot of other useful things for date handling in dateutil.